# My text widget overflows even if I use the overflow property

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I try to display a text widget inside a row but some sentences are too long. I don't know how to wrap them to the next line.

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(imageUrl, height: 100, width: 100, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
              Text(title, maxLines: 5, softWrap: true, overflow: TextOverflow.fade,textHeightBehavior: ,)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

This is my code.
[image: This is the error I get]

This is the error I get. I need to wrap the text to the next line without overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `Text` widget inside **`Expanded`** widget

Try this

```
 Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.network(imageUrl, height: 100, width: 100, fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                              Expanded(child: Text(title, maxLines: 5, softWrap: true, overflow: TextOverflow.fade,textHeightBehavior: ,))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```